# DatetimePicker on the modal not displaying completely

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datetimepicker

The Datetimepicker is not displaying fully in the Bootstrap v3.3.7 model, despite my attempts to present it there. The date time picker is partially visible and partially hidden; similarly, the issue also arises in a responsive manner (on small device like mobile). I've attached two images that demonstrate the issue in detail.
[image]

[image]

The HTML code here is

```
<!-- Admission All modal dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="AdmissionAllModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- modal header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">فہرست داخلہ دارجہ وار</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- /end modal header -->

            <!-- modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>داخلہ کی درجہ وار فہرست حاصل کرنے کے لیے ابتدائی اور آخری تاریخ کا اندراج کریں۔</h4>
                <form id="AdmissionAllFormModal" method="post" action="onlineadmission/AdmissionAllReport.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="loginLabel">ابتدائی تاریخ</label>
                        <div class="input-group datetimePicker1">
                            <input class="datetimePicker1 form-control" type="text"> 
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="loginLabel">آخری تاریخ</label>
                        <div class="input-group datetimePicker1">
                            <input class="datetimePicker1 form-control" type="text"> 
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="SubmitToDelete" value="تلاش کریں۔">
                </form>
            <!-- /modal footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end Admission All modal dialog -->
```

I'm using Bootstrap Datetimepicker version 4.17.47 and Bootstrap v3.3.7.
Is there anyone who can assist me in displaying Datetimepicker fully on the popup model? as in the example image
[image]

Comment: "model"... You mean **"modal"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by making overflow: visible. Now the correct answer is given below code here

```
.modal-content {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: (offtopic) You don't have to -vendor-prefix border-radius.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the date picker to not rely on the modal, and the modal size.
Add to modal css:

```
.modal{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1
 }
```

Comment: Hi, @Peleg Haham, thanks for reply, I try it, but the popup model disappear its not working.

Comment: Hi, can you upload this as a snippet ? it will be easier to help that way

Comment: I cannot understand what kind of snippet I share with you, I don't made any change in bootstrap model CSS, can you access remotely my PC to see the correct problem?

Comment: You can edit the post, copy the code to html/css/js snippet.

Comment: Bootstrap mod**a**l...